# Derivative of a term in a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

I am calculating a profit equation, and I need to find the derivative with respect to n. I am stuck on calculating
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}$$ 
where $c_i$ > 0. I see that if n decreases the value of the series will decrease, I just don't know what the derivative looks like, or if its even an acceptable question or process.

Any help or explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: $n$ being an integer can you change it by less than one unit ?

Comment: In this context (discrete variable), partial derivative doesn't makes sense. The *difference* makes sense. *Maybe* relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-difference_estimator.